# How can I fix the size of the main view after an initial auto-rotation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

Here are the steps:

1. Create a new project for the iPad.
2. Choose only Landscape Right / Left in general settings.
3. Change the view's orientation to be of landscape inside the storyboard.
4. Log the view's size after the viewDidLoad / Appear.

Although, inside the storyboard the view is set to (1024.0, 768.0)
it *logs* the opposite (768.0, 1024.0) as if the view rotates to landscape
after it has appeared in landscape mode.

I know, it's craze!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a new iPad single view project, chose only Landscape Right and Left in general settings, put this code in the controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("ViewDidLoad W: \(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width) H: \(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height)")
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    print("ViewDidAppear W: \(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width) H: \(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height)") 
}
```

And this is the output I got:

```
ViewDidLoad W: 1024.0 H: 768.0
ViewDidAppear W: 1024.0 H: 768.0
```

Changing the view controller orientation in the storyboard made no difference to the output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I've created an new view that sits on top of the main view as the main view of a new class that handles the entire app interface. Something like animator.view. It works fine!